# how to add items to a property (List<T>) of a generic type

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, system.reflection

I am making a Windows Form app to Edit Json data.
i have a class `StaticData` that is my Json (deserialised) object.

```
public class StaticData<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        public List<ColumnInfo> ColumnInfos { get; set; }
        public DatabasesTableException DatabaseTableException { get; set; }
        public List<T> DataTableContent { get; set; }
    }
```

An instance of this object is created at runtime with Reflection and added to a DataGridView.

Now my problem is to add or delete a row to that DataGridView but i have to add a new item to `public List<T> DataTableContent` first.

I am able to get the property `DataTableContent` with `StaticData.GetType().GetProperty("DataTableContent")`. but i am kinda stuck here.

#StillNewToReflection

Comment: Get type of underlying property, find there [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=net-5.0) method and invoke passing there required instance (see `GetValue` on `PropertyInfo`) and the instance of `T` you want to add.

Comment: `Type DataContent = StaticData.GetType().GetProperty("DataTableContent").GetType();` this = RuntimeProperty info. so i can't get the method Add()

Comment: Not `GetType` but `PropertyType`.

Comment: i also tried `List<object> DataContent = (List<object>)StaticData.GetType().GetProperty("DataTableContent").GetValue(StaticData);` to get it as a List but it can't cast :(

Comment: Yes, it can't cause `List` is [invariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) type. Why do you need to cast?